# MongoDB Connection for Spring Boot Application on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, spring-boot

What is the best way to configure a Spring Boot application to connect to MongoDB on Heroku?  I got it working specifying `spring.data.mongodb.uri` in the application.properties file, but I would like to set the connection up, so that I can keep the application pointing to my local MongoDB during development, while being able to push to Heroku without reconfiguring the connection URI each time.

Thanks,
   Jerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use profile-specific configuration to specify the URIs to use during development and when deploying to Heroku. A file named `application-{profile}.properties` will only be loaded when the matching profile is active, i.e. you could use a file named `application-heroku.properties` and enable the `heroku` profile when deploying to Heroku. Any profile-specific configuration will override the default configuration in `application.properties`. You can enable a profile using `spring.profiles.active`, for example:

```
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=heroku
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Andy.  Using profiles is a good option, especially if I need to specify other environment specific parameters.  I've also managed to get it working using the following parameter in Procfile `-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=$MONGOHQ_URL`.

Comment: I had a problem establishing the connection with the DB, because of the retryWrites option. This solved the problem: spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGODB_URI}?retryWrites=false

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGOLAB_URI}
```